# Упаковка графика Matplotlib и полотна Tkinter на один объект root

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, matplotlib

Я делаю **`2d`** - программу, которая стоит график движения тела, брошенного под углом к горизонту. Для этого я использую *Tkinter* и *Matplotlib*.

Я никак не могу найти способ вывести `Canvas`(холст) *tkinter* и график так, чтобы холст был слева, а график - справа (и консоль интерактивного управления просмотром графика - также справа - под графиком, а не под всем приложением).

При этом мне важно, чтобы всё было упаковано методом `grid`. Пока мне удалось собрать их упаковщиком `pack()`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from tkinter import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from math import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Embedding in Tk")

canvas0 = Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 500,
                bg = 'blue', bd = 0,
                borderwidth = 0,
                highlightthickness = 0) 
#canvas0.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=0) 
#Входные и расчётные данные
#U = float(input("U = "))
#a = float(input("a = "))
U = 200
a = 30
PI = 3.14
a1 = (PI * float(a)) / 180
g = 9.8
L = U*U*sin(2*a1)/g 

fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 5), dpi=100) #Размеры графика

x = np.linspace(0, L, 100)

fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x, x*sin(a1)/cos(a1)-x*x*9.8/2/U/U/cos(a1)/cos(a1)) #111 - положение



canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

canvas0.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from math import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Embedding in Tk")

canvas0 = Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 500,
                bg = 'blue', bd = 0,
                borderwidth = 0,
                highlightthickness = 0) 
canvas0.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=0)

#Входные и расчётные данные
#U = float(input("U = "))
#a = float(input("a = "))
U = 200
a = 30
PI = 3.14
a1 = (PI * float(a)) / 180
g = 9.8
L = U*U*sin(2*a1)/g 

fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 5), dpi=100)     
x = np.linspace(0, L, 100)

fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x, x*sin(a1)/cos(a1)-x*x*9.8/2/U/U/cos(a1)/cos(a1)) #111 - положение

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=3, rowspan=20)
canvas.draw()

toolbarFrame = Frame(master=root)
toolbarFrame.grid(row=21, column=4)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, toolbarFrame)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо - всё отлично вышло

Comment: @ВсеволодРостовский пожалуйста